# How do I change the media bar image from a webpage?

Tags: html, windows, media-player

Apologies for the poor wording. How do I change the thumbnail and information displaying in the below "media bar" as sites like YouTube do?

[image]

I presume the changes needed are `<meta>` tags on my HTML webpage but I'm not even sure what this thing is called so I don't even know where to begin searching.

Is this something you set with specific a specific `<meta>` tag, or with attributes on my HTML document or HTML elements such as on the `audio` or `video` elements?

YouTube's changes of the thumbnail and information in the bar:

[image]